# Any alternative to redirect_to in rails api only application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to redirect to another `url` in rails controller action. like

```
def action_name
  redirect_to url
end
```

I know i can do it simply using the above method. But i want to redirect in only one action in all my application. because of this i don't want to include this in controller.

```
include ActionController::Redirecting
```

is there any other way to redirect to a uri in api only applications. Thanks.

Comment: render 302 status and the Location header?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`respond_with`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) which will respond with a appropriate response depending on the request type and the status of the model you pass to `respond_with`.

```
def create
  @thing = Thing.create(thing_params)
  respond_with(@thing)
end
```

This will give `201 - Created` status and a location header if the the request is successful and a `422 - Unprocessable Entity` if the validations fail.

Alternativly you can use `head` to [send a header only response](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses) with no body.

```
def action_name
  head :not_found, location: url
end
```

Note that `:not_found` could be any appropriate HTTP status.

Comment: `respond_with` is even more powerful if you add the [responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders).

Answer (score 1):

If your using Rails API:

Route your path, and take the `params`, and return:

```
redirect_to controller: "client", action: "get_name", params: request.query_parameters and return
```